# gaps between word and greek angle quotes

Tags: xetex, punctuation, greek

I use XeLatex to write a thesis in greek. My problem is that writing «word» displayed as « word » , with a gap before and after the word. How can I change that? I don't want these gaps.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please provide a *minimal* working example with which we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It was problem with kerkis fonts. With liberation Serif fonts is ok!